# Dynamic ActionBar title from a Fragment using AndroidX Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using the new [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/) component from Android Jetpack.

The root Activity setup is quite simple:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.navigationFragment)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)

    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

It works well when the Fragment's title is defined in the navigation graph. But for one Fragment, I want to set the title dynamically.

I tried with `findNavController().currentDestination.label = "Hello world"` but it does nothing.

I could of course use a trick like `(activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.title = "Hello world"`, but I feel that it will break the magic that `setupActionBarWithNavController()` does for me. It there any way to update the Action Bar title dynamically?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

As of `1.0.0-alpha08`, you can have the NavigationUI bits dynamically set the title... if the dynamic bits are arguments on the navigation action.

So, for example, in your navigation graph, you could have something like this:

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/displayFragment"
    android:name="com.commonsware.jetpack.sampler.nav.DisplayFragment"
    android:label="Title: {title}" >
    <argument
      android:name="modelId"
      app:argType="string" />
    <argument
      android:name="title"
      app:argType="string" />
  </fragment>
```

Here, the `android:label` attribute for our `<fragment>` has an argument name wrapped in braces (`{title}` in `"Title: {title}"`. The app bar's title will then be set to the value of the label, with `{title}` replaced by the value of the `title` argument.

If you need something more elaborate than that — for example, you want to look up the model by ID and read a property from it — you will need to use more manual approaches, such as those outlined in other answers to this question.

Comment: This solution is not working in navigation version `2.1.0-alpha02`. It directly printing the `Title: {title}` as action bar title.

Comment: @RohitMaurya: If there is no bug report for this, and you can create a project that reproduces the problem, file a bug report.

Comment: To add; value binding seems to be sensitive to additional whitespaces in an argument wrapped with braces. I noticed that `{ title }` would cause my app to crash where as `{title}` worked as expected. Just a minor gotcha incase it catches anyone else out.

Comment: @DacreDenny: Nice find! I reproduced that one easily enough and [filed an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147083785).

Comment: Of cause in real live that title would always be a string resource. So we should show the usage of a string resource with an argument instead of a fixed title string that is not translatable.

Comment: What about subtitle? And what about an object been passed as argument, how to get its String value?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira: "What about subtitle?" -- AFAIK, `Fragment` does not have that concept. If you are displaying a subtitle in your own code, you would need to handle that yourself. "And what about an object been passed as argument, how to get its String value? " -- for `android:label`, that would appear to be covered in the answer (`title` is an argument). Otherwise, you use the normal Navigation APIs for that, which depend on whether or not you are using the "safe args" plugin.

Comment: What if I want to combine a string argument with a string resource? Is that possible?

Comment: @BenjaminMenrad: AFAIK, you would have to do that yourself in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I already expected that as I haven't found a way to do that. Nevertheless I wanted to ask :)

Comment: So you also have to pass the title as an argument? How is that done?

Comment: @behelit: You put the `<argument>` element in the nav graph, as I have shown above. Any actions that point to this destination would need to provide that argument. Then, your Java/Kotlin code that navigates using that action would need to provide that argument (e.g., via a Safe Args-generated "directions" class).

Comment: If you want L10N, `android:label="@string/my_title"` and in strings.xml, define `<string name="title_search">Search: {keyword}</string>`

Comment: I needed exactly the "more elaborate" option described in this answer: use the `modelId` to asynchronously load the model and then use the model's name as the action bar title. Setting the action bar's title in the fragment's `onResume` method worked. When I rotate the phone, the title is set again to what I want it to be.

Comment: This solution is great if the name used for the title is known at the time of the fragment creation. However, if the app bar title needs to be changed programmatically after the fragment is created, *[@Patriotic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60597473/2253682)* is the best fit.

Comment: @RohitMaurya It's working with ver.2.3.5

Comment: I don't know why my app sometimes shows `Title: {myTitle}` as fragment title and sometimes it shows `Title: correct Title!`. For this I tried to add `defaultvalue="No Data" but this make app uncompilable, The error is that: selected action accept no argument.

Answer (score 44):

The title can be changed in the fragment by casting the activity as `AppCompatActivity`.

**Kotlin**

```
(requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Hello"
```

**Java**

```
((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello");
```

Comment: This is the only solution thus far that works with programmatically changing the Navigation UI's action bar/app bar after the `label` is defined in the Navigation Graph.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks :D

Comment: Just noticed that Android Studio returns back a warning saying : "Method invocation 'getSupportActionBar' may produce 'NullPointerException'". I was wondering is there any way to resolve this other than putting (if/else) ?

Comment: Doesn't work because fragment references FragmentActivity not AppCompatActivity

Comment: @JPM it doesn't matter. Fragment references the parent activity. So this works as long as your parent activity is AppCompatActivity.

Comment: One issue is if you put this in `onViewCreated` it works on navigation but fails if the fragment is rotated because the action bar is not available in `onViewCreated` when this is called because of the rotation. Instead put it in `onStart`.

Answer (score 19):

Taking consideration that your host activity is `MainActivity`, just add the following code to your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` fun

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

// setting title according to fragment
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { 
    controller, destination, arguments ->
        toolbar.title = navController.currentDestination?.label
}
```

Comment: Agree with this answer if you only have one activity. Simply set label in nav_main.xml

Comment: The title must come from the fragment and the code should be in the fragment itself. 
The activity should not have to know about every possible fragment.
That's the reason we move from the activity implementing interfaces to support their fragments to Jetpack navigation and ViewModels.

Comment: The navigation destination is already given as an argument, so use it:

`toolbar.title = destination.label`
or
`supportActionBar?.title = destination.label`

Answer (score 11):

If you use toolbar on setSupportActionBar in Activity and you would like to change its title in fragment, then below code may gonna help you ;)

```
(requireActivity() as MainActivity).toolbar.title = "Title here"
```

Answer (score 9):

As of now, The Jetpack Navigation Architecture components do not provide any "built in" way to do this, and you'll have to implement your own "custom" method for doing it.

There is an existing feature request to get functionality for dynamic labels on destinations added to the new Jetpack Navigation Architecture Components. If you are here because you want/need this functionality, please star the existing feature request, here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80267266

Comment: I see that the issue is fixed but still I can't the proper way. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504353/115145) that I just added.

Answer (score 8):

**Remove label from graph.xml file**

```
android:label="fragment_info"
```

and use old school approach if you want to set title of the fragment dynamically from the fragment itself

```
getActivity().setTitle("Your Title");
```

Comment: This does not work if you need to make decisions with a navigationListener based on the navigation id, which happens to be the label defined in the nav graph.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to use ViewModel and LiveData, attach viewmodel to your activity and fragments, add a livedata field inside viewmodel

```
val title = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

From your activity observe this field, and if it is changed update the toolbar title

```
viewModel?.title?.observe(this, Observer { 
        my_toolbar.title=it
    })
```

From your desired fragment change the title field inside the viewmodel

```
viewModel?.title?.value="New title"
```

Comment: That could me a solution. However with the navigation component I have way more than one Fragment in the Activity. How would I now in the activity which Fragment is visible and how to react to it. It seems cumbersome.

Comment: You can use multiple fragments in activity, you changing the title from the fragment, it doesn't matter which fragment it is, just change the viewmodel field title to something else, and activity will know about the change in title value, and it will update the toolbar title accordingly

Comment: With the Navigation component that itself changes the ActionBar title, it does not really seem a good idea.

Comment: I like this solution, since I can't determine the fragment label when passing the arguments I decided to create base fragment class that changes toolbar title through live data in model and all the subclasses just implement abstract property to provide the title. And I removed all the labels in nav graph, so the Navigation component doesn't interfere. It's not super elegant but I guess it's not so ugly either.

Answer (score 4):

Well, now the Navigation UI supports this feature. Now the `ActionBar` title changes dynamically. You just have to setup the `ActionBar` with the `NavController`.

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

private lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    preferedTheme()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_controller_fragment)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

And set action bar label in nav graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
          android:name="com.cinderellaman.general.ui.fragments.MainFragment"
          android:label="General"
          tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment"/>
```

And now its also support Navigate Up:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

Comment: You might want to pimp your code a bit by using extension functions which are available in the `navigation-ui-ktx` artifact, e.g. `BottomNavigationView#setupWithNavController`, `AppCompatActivity#setupActionBarWithNavController` and `NavController#navigateUp`.

Answer (score 2):

Until the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80267266) will be fixed, simple listener is working to me:

```
/**
 * Temporary solution to dynamically change title of actionbar controlled by Navigation component
 * Should be removed as soon as the bug on Navigation will be fixed: (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80267266)
 */
interface TempToolbarTitleListener {
    fun updateTitle(title: String)
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TempToolbarTitleListener {

    ...

    override fun updateTitle(title: String) {
        binding.toolbar.title = title
    }
}
```

change title from fragment:

```
(activity as TempToolbarTitleListener).updateTitle("custom title")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @kaustubh-trivedi answer, and if you are using MVVM (like the Android Studio FirstFragment/SecondFragment example):

**KOTLIN version**

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

// setting title according to fragment
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { 
    controller, destination, arguments ->
        toolbar.title = navController.currentDestination?.label
}
```

**JAVA version**

```
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                binding.toolbar.setTitle(destination.getLabel());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add addOnNavigatedListener inside your activity, and based on current destination change the title

```
 findNavController(nav_host_fragment).addOnNavigatedListener { controller, destination ->
        when(destination.id) {
            R.id.destination1 -> {
                my_toolbar.title= "Some title"
            }
            R.id.destination2 -> {
                my_toolbar.title= "Othertitle"

            }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want my Activity to know about the Fragments' titles. They should be self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

If your title is received from a concatenated string, for example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) 
  requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
  
if(actionBar!=null)                   
   actionBar.setTitle(count + "items");
```

Comment: What if actionBar is null? I mean it is possible to be null?

Comment: It's like asking what if a reference to a text view that you did not include in the XML is null.

Comment: Anyway, you can surround getSupportActionBar() with a null check just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

As per the below solutions, there is **no need to access the toolbar** manually.

If you are going to pass the Model into the destinations fragment.
Then you can do as below.

Override `toString()` method in your model class

```
data class UserModel(
    val userId: String = ""
    val firstName: String = "",
    val lastName: String = ""  
) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$firstName $lastName"
    }
}
```

Now, in the `nav_grap.xml`  file, do as below. `android:label="{UserData}"` will be fetch label from toString() method of model class.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/messagesFragment"
    android:name="com.app.mydemoapp.ui.messages.MessagesFragment"
    android:label="{UserData}"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_messages">

    <argument
        android:name="UserData"
        app:argType="com.app.mydemoapp.model.UserModel" />

</fragment>
```

I hope, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On trying the activity's title it seems to override the title for fragment. Being on safe side you must put on `onResume`.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    activity?.toolbar.title = "YOUR_TITLE_HERE"
}
```

it works for me !

**Note :** Must have Toolbar Widget in activity

Add toolbar like this in your activity's xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Other Widgets -->

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code inside yourfragment.java if you are using navigation components , and you want to change the label of your fragment programmatically in JAVA

```
  Navigation.findNavController(view).addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController navController, @NonNull NavDestination navDestination, @Nullable Bundle bundle) {

           navController.findDestination(R.id.YOUR_FRAGMENT_ID_HERE).setLabel(YOUR_LABEL_HERE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: does this overrides what we have defined using `addOnDestinationChangedListener` on the main activity?

Answer (score -2):

you can remove **android:label** in navigation graph then write in **onCreateView()**

```
activity?.title="your title"
```

Comment: In case someone wonders why the negative votes: this solution is far from valid because the question already specifies that the activity is using a toolbar with `setupActionBarWithNavController()`, therefore, using `activity?.title` won't ever work because it's being overriden by the `toolbar`'s title.